# Trouble while loading R package "rgl"

Tags: macos, r, rgl

When I try to load the package I get this error message:

```
Error : .onLoad in loadNamespace() fehlgechlagen, Details:   
  Call: rgl 
  Error: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) 
Error: Laden von Paket/Namensraum für ‘rgl’ fehlgeschlagen
```

That translation is just "Failed to load 'rgl' package/namespace".

All dependencies are installed. I tried to de- and reinstall it using `package.install()` without success. 
I'am running OSX 10.6, R version 2.15.0.

Has anyone ideas where the problem could be?

EDIT:
I was asked to do the following

`install.packages("rgl", verbose=TRUE)`

As result I got:

> Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
>     unbenutzte(s) Argument(e) (verbose = TRUE)
>
> Warnung in download.packages(pkgs, destdir = tmpd, available = available,  :
>     Download von Paket ‘rgl’ fehlgeschlagen

Comment: How did you install `rgl`?  What OS are you running?  What version of `rgl`?  What version of R?

Comment: Sys.info()? What does that tell us? Guessing Windows here.

Comment: OSX is one of the tags... So Mac I'm pretty sure.

Comment: I installed it with `install.packages()`. No problems. Running OSX 10.6, R version 2.15.0.

Comment: Try again with `install.packages("rgl", verbose = TRUE)` and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying to install it from source. If you have subversion installed the following code in Terminal should work. Which I got from http://danbri.org/words/2011/12/08/761.

```
svn checkout svn://svn.r-forge.r-project.org/svnroot/rgl
R CMD INSTALL ./rgl/pkg/rgl –configure-args=”–disable-carbon” rgl
```

HTH